# Indexing of moveToPosition of Cursor in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am using a pre-populated database in my application which has 70 rows of data. I am using a cursor with its methods, `moveToFirst()` , `moveToLast()` and `moveToPosition(int)` .

My question is, does the Cursor position use zero-based indexing?
 ie are my values  (0 to 69) or (1 to 70). More specifically, if I wish to do the same as `cursor.moveToFirst()` should I use `cursor.moveToPosition(0)` or `cursor.moveToPosition(1)`

I have also tried referring to the android developers page, where it is given that the columns are zero-based indexed. But, no info is given regarding the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation of `moveToPosition()` says:
`position` - the zero-based position to move to.
So, your rows numbered from 0 to 69.